# My Tkinter code for displaying every field from a database isn't displaying in the tkinter widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, sqlite, listbox

I have a backend file and a frontend file, and I want it so that for the view function, it queries the database and outputs each row (on a new line) to the Listbox widget.

How can I edit my code so that it 1) Outputs to the Listbox widget rather than printing into the console and 2) Outputs each database row on a new row in the Listbox widget?

I can't seem to figure it out and I can't find any resources.

Thank you

**Here's my backend code:**

```
def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Orders.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(Reference REAL, Date TEXT, Name TEXT, SubTotal REAL, VAT REAL, Total REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Orders.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    print (rows)
```

**And here's my frontend code:**

```
  from tkinter import *
from backend import hello
from backend import connect
from backend import insert
from backend import view
from backend import search


window = Tk()

l1=Label(window, text ="Order Reference ID")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l1=Label(window, text ="Date")
l1.grid(row=0,column=2)

l1=Label(window, text ="Name")
l1.grid(row=1,column=0)

l1=Label(window, text ="SubTotal")
l1.grid(row=1,column=2)

l1=Label(window, text ="VAT")
l1.grid(row=2,column=0)

l1=Label(window, text ="Total Cost")
l1.grid(row=2,column=2)


referenceID_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window,textvariable=referenceID_text)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

date_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(window,textvariable=date_text)
e2.grid(row=0,column=3)

name_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window,textvariable=name_text)
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)

subtotal_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(window,textvariable=subtotal_text)
e4.grid(row=1,column=3)

vat_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(window,textvariable=vat_text)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1)

total_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(window,textvariable=total_text)
e4.grid(row=2,column=3)

list1=Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
list1.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)

#Attatch scrollbar
sb1=Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=2,column=2,rowspan=6)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

#Define buttons
b1=Button(window,text="View All", width=15, command=lambda: view())
b1.grid(row=3,column=3)

b1=Button(window,text="Search Entry", width=15, command=lambda: search())
b1.grid(row=4,column=3)

b1=Button(window,text="Close", width=15)
b1.grid(row=5,column=3)

b1=Button(window,text="Add Entry", width=15, command=lambda: insert())
b1.grid(row=6,column=3)

b1=Button(window,text="Delete Selected", width=15, command=lambda: delete())
b1.grid(row=7,column=3)



connect()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend you reduce this down to a [mcve] by eliminating all of the widgets except the listbox, and removing the dependency on the database. You can simulate the data from the query with a static list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to [`insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) directly the rows returned by the query in the `Listbox` widget.

First change the function `view` to return the `rows` :

```
def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Orders.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

Then create another function that loop on the results to insert them :

```
def insert_rows():
    for row in view():
        list1.insert(END, row)

b1=Button(window,text="View All", width=15, command=lambda: insert_rows())
```

Now if you want a better output value, you could format a string with a syntax like :

```
list1.insert(END, '{} {} {} {} {} Total : {}'.format(*row))
```

(Just make sure about the order of fields by naming them in your query)

Comment: Thank you. When I add the lsit1.insert section to the frontend (under the list1 bits), I get this message in the shell when clicking view all: http://prntscr.com/h3z57z

It also then looks like this, which it doesn't do if I leave the list1.insert bit out - it works perfectly otherwise - thank you! http://prntscr.com/h3z5ta

Comment: the line `list1.insert(END, '{} {} {} {} {} Total : {}'.format(*row))` was suggested for replacing `list1.insert(END, row)` in the loop, where `row` is defined